Joint submission in two Physical Review journals: can I use the same plots?
I am submitting two papers to two journals from the Physical Review journals family; this is a joint submission. I am going to use the same plots in these papers. Am I right that it would not cause any problem with copyright as the publisher is the same?

I think you are just better off asking the publisher/editor/whoever.

As Allure proved, this question is answerable based on the guidelines provided by the journal. Therefore, it should not be closed in my opinion.

@TheDoctor While that may be true, if it depends on the journal(s), we don't want this same question for every pair of journals out there.

@AzorAhai-him- The answer covers not only two journals, but it is general to Physical Review journals, which is the most important publishing venue in Physics. For me it sounds like broad enough, if it was general it wouldn't be possible to answer. And this situation is probably more common in these journals,

@TheDoctor So you'd be ok with having one of these questions for the most important venue in every field? Here, I'd be OK with the question being generalized and the answer changed to "In physics ..." and then we can add answers for other fields. There are fields besides physics.

Yes, I would. :)

@TheDoctor Is "Physical Review" the name of the publisher or what?

@AzorAhai-him- Physical Review Journals is an umbrella that encompasses 20 journals published by the American Physical Society.

It should be fine copyright-wise, but you still want the letter and the full article to be be distinct from each other. As stated in the Publishing Guidelines

In all cases, the longer article should present considerably more (or different) information than contained in the abbreviated publication, and it should lead to a substantially improved understanding of the subject. Some duplication of figures, tables, and text material will often be appropriate, but should be limited and must be properly referenced.)

If you're "using the same plots" in both publications, as opposed to re-using some of the plots, you may want to check with the publisher that what you're doing is still appropriate. As a side note, I'm not sure how enforced the "properly referenced" part is. For example, there seems to be an overlap between some of the panels in this PRL and ones in this PRD but it does not seem to be explicitly mentioned, which agrees with what I've seen in PRL-PRB joint submissions.

If this figure is some general illustration that does not show your original data but rather illustrates the introduction (e.g. showing schematic of your experiment or previously published results), I see no problem at all. However, if it illustrates your original results, I would be a bit more careful. If it's a joint publication, it should be possible to cite your PRL paper in the PRD paper as the source of the figure ("reproduced from Ref. X"). Joint submissions are typically reviewed by the same referees, and if I got two papers for review with the same figure appearing in the results section, I would probably consider it as an attempt of a duplicate publication. At least, this thought would cross my mind and I would need to look for arguments in favor or against it. However, if you cite the second paper as the origin of that figure, this concern would be resolved immediately.
